# Magento 2 - How to change fotorama nav shaft thumbnail image size - for grouped products?

Tags: magento2, product, grouped-products, gallery, fotorama

I need to change the size of the small images below the gallery, but only for products of type `grouped`

[image]

Normaly you can change the size in the file `THEME/etc/view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            ...
            <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
                <width>110</width>
                <height>110</height>
            </image>
            ...
```

So I tried to change it for grouped products only like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_GroupedProduct">
            <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
                <width>129</width>
                <height>129</height>
            </image>
        </images>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            ...
            <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
                <width>110</width>
                <height>110</height>
            </image>
            ...
```

Then I flushed the cache. But it does not work. The image size still stays 110px instead of 129px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Had to overwrite the method `getImageAttribute` of the class `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery`